# Processing Input file in c

Tags: c, file, parsing, input

So Im just wondering about a few tips on doing a scheduler simulation.

So far, I just want to input a file at the command line i.e. /.scheduler in.file

The in.file holds the following information:

```
./Job1.txt
./Job2.txt
./Job3.txt
./Job4.txt
```

Each Job .txt file has random lines of code. With only the first line being significant. The first line is starting 'tick' time.

Job A:

```
10
1fi
3sdkfj
4ksdkk
5kdkfk
6kdkjf
7dkjkfd
9dkkf
10dku
```

At the moment I just want to take the in.file and order the 'Job' files in order of their arrival tick time i.e. first line.

My code thus far:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#include "projscheduler.h"



/* I/O Files */
//static char *inputFile;
char * in;
static FILE *input;

/*Scheduled jobs indexed by PID*/
struct job list[20];

/* the next job to schedule */
//static struct job *job_next = NULL;

/* Time */
time clock;

/*Initialises job list*/
static void initialise_list(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); i++) {
        list[i].parameters.pid = -1;
    }
}

/** Read and parse input from input file */
static void parse_input(void) 
{
    char    buffer[BUFSIZ];
    //int   jobs;



    initialise_list();



    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) )   
    {
        pid j_pid;
        sscanf(buffer, "./%d.txt", &j_pid);

    } 

}   


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    if ( (input = fopen(in, "r")) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
    }

    parse_input(); 


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

HEADER FILE:

```
/**
 * Simulation of a process scheduler
*/

//#ifndef SCHEDULER_H_
#define SCHEDULER_H_

#include <stddef.h>


/* types */
/** units of time */
typedef long time;
/** process identifier */
typedef int pid;

/** Information about a job of interest to the task scheduler */
struct job_data {

/* pid of this process */
    pid pid;
    /* time process starts */
    time start;
    /* time needed to finish */
    time finish;
    /* time spent processing so far */
    time scheduled;
    /* size of the process */
    size_t size;

};

struct job {

    /* Various parameters used by the scheduler */
    char job_name[BUFSIZ];
    struct job_data parameters;
    /* next job to be scheduled */
    //struct job *next;


};
```

Comment: Perhaps this should go on codereview.

Comment: My bad! Sorry, Im just reviewing it as I havnt slept! Ive made progress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what problems you are having exactly but I can see the following errors in the code:

- In the `initialise_list()` function the `for` loop will be iterating too many times and going beyond the bounds the of array:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(list); i++) {
  ```

as `sizeof(list)` will return the number of bytes occupied by the array which is `20 * sizeof(struct job)`. Change to:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]); i++) {
```

- this is a missing left parenthesis from `fopen()` attempt (meaning the posted code does not compile):

  ```
  if( (input = fopen(inputfile, "r") == NULL )
  ```

should be:

```
    if( (input = fopen(inputfile, "r")) == NULL )
```

- `proj` is an initialised `char*` and this will mostly likely cause a segmentation fault:

  ```
  char *proj;
  sscanf(buffer, "./%s.txt", proj);
  ```

Comment: My problem is that Im not sure how to open the file 'file.in' and gather information from the Job text files that are files in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: Thanks heaps I now understand the first for loop creating problems... just the rest of it now :(

Comment: Im updating my code with a bit of your help... let us know what you think! cheers legend

Comment: One thing im unclear with... The in.file essentially has text files in it represented by there address. I want to take the job pid i.e. JobA then also get the 'tick' from within that text file... Im not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#include "projscheduler.h"



/* I/O Files */
//static char *inputFile;
char * in;
static FILE *input;
static FILE *cur;
/*Scheduled jobs indexed by PID*/
struct job list[20];

/* the next job to schedule */
//static struct job *job_next = NULL;

/* Time */
time clock;

/*Initialises job list*/
static void initialise_list(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); i++) {
        list[i].parameters.pid = -1;
    }
}

/*Order Jobs*/
/*=static void order_jobs(void)
{
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); i++)
    {


}
*/

/** Read and parse input from input file */
static void parse_input(void) 
{
    char    buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char    lines[BUFSIZ];
    int jobs = 0;
    struct  job *current;


    initialise_list();



    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) )   
    {


        time start;
        char  buf[20];
        sscanf(buffer,"./%s/", buf);
        cur = fopen(buf, "r" );





        fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), cur);
        sscanf(lines,"%ld", &start);


        current = &list[jobs];

        current->job_id = buf;
        current->parameters.start = start;

        jobs++;

    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++)
    {
        printf("%s starts at %ld\n", list[i].job_id, list[i].parameters.start);
    }   

}   


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    in = argv[1];
    if ( (input = fopen(in, "r")) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
    }

    parse_input();



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Above, I successfully read the in.file and extracted the first line from each address representing a text file.

Code above associated with following header:

```
/**
 * Simulation of a process scheduler
*/

//#ifndef SCHEDULER_H_
#define SCHEDULER_H_

#include <stddef.h>


/* types */
/** units of time */
typedef long time;
/** process identifier */
typedef int pid;

/** Information about a job of interest to the task scheduler */
struct job_data {

/* pid of this process */
    pid pid;
    /* time process starts */
    time start;
    /* time needed to finish */
    time finish;
    /* time spent processing so far */
    time scheduled;
    /* size of the process */
    size_t size;

};

struct job {

    /* Various parameters used by the scheduler */
    char * job_id;
    struct job_data parameters;
    /* next job to be scheduled */
    //struct job *next;


};
```